# Is the "Ask for Review" alert part of StoreKit or is it custom?

Tags: ios, swift

Is the alert on the right still part of `StoreKit` and shown automatically after a user chooses a star rating and pressing submit? or is it a custom alert that needs to be added after    `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()`

It's not possible to test in development mode as the submit button is disabled, and not more than 3 times in production.  Is that second alert shown? or is it something that needs to be added in order to allow users to add a written review (not a rating)

[image: The review flow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a built-in UI. According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview):

> When you call this method in your shipping app and a rating/review
> request view is displayed, the system handles the entire process for
> you.